# specify region in "aws cloudformation delete-stack"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

Stack create allows a region paramater.

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --region <> --template-body <>
```

I have a cloudformation stack in all regions of an account, how do i delete it in a region?

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name myteststack
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `--region` parameter. `region` is a global option in AWS CLI, and can be passed for all region-specific resources.

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name myteststack --region <>
```